# Google sheets conditional formatting depending on other cell

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to make every cell in range A2:G21 green if its value is lower than A24. I thought It would be quite easy but I just can't figure it out.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select from A2 to G21 and apply a *Custom formula is* of

```
=A2<$A$24
```